# How do fabrics, impermeability, buoyancy, and swimwear length enhance a swimmer's performance?

Tags: equipment, swimming, technology

In 2008, Speedo launched the [LZR Racer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZR_Racer), a high-tech swimwear.  Since high-tech swimwear were launched, over 130 world records have been broken.

As a result, [FINA](http://www.fina.org/H2O/), the International Swimming Federation, banned full-body length and high-tech swimwear starting in 2010.

The LZR Racer used a "high-technology swimwear fabric composed of woven elastane-nylon and polyurethane." How do fabrics, impermeability, buoyancy, and swimwear length enhance a swimmer's performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fabrics** are used to improve shape retention to reduce vibration, and increase muscle compression to retain muscle shape to reduce fatigue and power loss.

High-tech swimwear transforms a "less than perfect" physique into an ideal physique for swimming. Also, seams in high-tech swimwear are [ultrasonically welded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasonic_welding) rather than stitched, to further promote the streamline effect.

**Impermeability** reduces friction between water and the fabric, and also reduces drag.

Speedo added polyurethane panels that repelled water. Reducing aerodynamic properties increases a swimmer's speed in the water.

**Buoyancy** elevates a swimmer higher in the water.

Some swimmers wore two articles of high-tech swimwear to achieve a buoyant effect.

**Swimwear length:** Full-body length swimwear covers more surface area of the body. This works hand-in-hand with fabrics to achieve the compressive, impermeable, and buoyant benefits of high-tech swimwear.